# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. And three methods I tried

Tags: python, pytorch

I am stuck in a loop. I am running a pytorch program. There is a section I had to resize the image,

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    part1, part2, part3, label = self.data[index]
    temp = np.array(part3)
    temp.resize(32,32)
    img = np.stack((temp,temp,temp), axis=-1)
    return img, int(label)
```

The original size is (150,312).

When I run this, I get accuracy of 100% from the second try, which is too good to be true. I am suspecting the resize is cause of this issue. (Please let me know if there is other possible reasons) Thus I am trying to increase the image size to at least 128,128. But if I do increase the image size to 128,128 I get,

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 256.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.91 GiB total capacity; 10.40 GiB already allocated; 130.56 MiB free; 11.08 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I tried several solutions.

1: `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`
2: `gc.collect()`

Both of these did not make any difference.

3: Decrease image size to 64,64 ((40,40)did not cause any errors but the accuracy is 100%)
Got

`RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0`

4: Change the batch size.
Batch size 32 still caused CUDA out of memory error, and 16 causes

```
RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
```

Please give me any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how big is your model?

Comment: where can i check that?

Comment: I mean how much memory are you trying to allocate in total?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: @user253751 Just 256MiB

Comment: then something else is using all your GPU memory. Presumably some is graphics but not that much. Check for stray programs that shouldn't still be running?

Comment: This is a DM server, but no one is using at the time. Is there a way to quit all screens or other programs running?

Comment: Updated Question.

Answer (score -1):

Your model and/or data is too large to fit into your memory.
3 ways to solve this problem:

1. Get another GPU
2. Use less data or make the model smaller
3. Use Data Generators to load data on the fly. I recommend this read for PyTorch: [https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel)